# Accordion tabs do not open after 1st click

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, accordion

I am trying to create an accordion for a product bundle for my future website using bootstrap.

I have created a working test version here: http://35.177.108.249/test/
Source code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Product 1</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam laoreet turpis quis eros rutrum ornare. Phasellus vehicula quam ac arcu pulvinar, at consectetur erat ultricies. Etiam cursus vulputate purus, ac ullamcorper lacus. Nam justo quam, finibus et diam vel, condimentum congue magna. Aliquam non elit vel dui malesuada pellentesque. Sed sed dapibus nulla. Donec finibus ex ut diam accumsan consectetur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a  class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Product 2</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam laoreet turpis quis eros rutrum ornare. Phasellus vehicula quam ac arcu pulvinar, at consectetur erat ultricies. Etiam cursus vulputate purus, ac ullamcorper lacus. Nam justo quam, finibus et diam vel, condimentum congue magna. Aliquam non elit vel dui malesuada pellentesque. Sed sed dapibus nulla. Donec finibus ex ut diam accumsan consectetur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a  class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Product 3</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam laoreet turpis quis eros rutrum ornare. Phasellus vehicula quam ac arcu pulvinar, at consectetur erat ultricies. Etiam cursus vulputate purus, ac ullamcorper lacus. Nam justo quam, finibus et diam vel, condimentum congue magna. Aliquam non elit vel dui malesuada pellentesque. Sed sed dapibus nulla. Donec finibus ex ut diam accumsan consectetur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All works great no problem, now when I try to apply the same code to my product bundle its not working correctly, only the first tab opens and closes, while the rest dont open up after 1 click.

http://35.177.108.249/product/bundle-product-test

Not really sure where I am going wrong and would like some advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second page, all the panels have the same `id`. Bootstrap uses these to decide which panel to open and close. Since you have multiple, it always chooses the first one. To fix this, you should change `id="collapseOne"` to something unique in each of the product bodies, and change the `href="#collapseOne` on the tab control above it accordingly.

Comment: Easy mistake to make, I've certainly done it before! Some things just need another pair of eyes.

Comment: I fixed it! Had to pass unique ID through php.. just a question, any idea why now all tabs start up opened up. On the first example only 1 tab is open and the rest are close, while on the bundle they all start up opened.

Comment: They all have the class `panel-default` on them - Only the one you want opened initially should have that class.

Comment: Thanks! Thats more tricky.. as each product is generated the same way, so if I pass panel-default it does it for all of them.

Comment: Hi, was just looking through how to do this and noticed that on my working example they all have panel default, yet only the 1st one opens. I was thinking of writing a while loop but the problem is all products are generated using this template of divs and functions, so even if i make a while ($i < 1) and set some conditions it will just repeat the while loop for each product anyway. Any idea why on the working example it works on with all of them having panel default?

Comment: Apologies! I had the wrong class. It's the `in` class in `class="panel-collapse collapse in"`. If the panel has this class, it'll be open by default. Your link is down at the moment, but my guess would be that they all have this class. https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

Comment: Hi, it was down as my loop is not working.. I just restored it.  Thank you very much for your reply! I got the main idea that it needs to have a certain class to be opened. Problem is in wordpress each product that gets created in the bundle runs the same code over and over and any loops inside the code will repeat as well without keeping any data from last run :/